# Are zero inflated models appropriate if the predictor/x variable is the one that is zero-inflated?

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, continuous-data, zero-inflation

As the title suggests.  I was under the impression that zero-inflated models are generally used when zero values are over-represented among the response/y variables, but now I am dealing with a dataset that has the converse characteristic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. In general, regression modeling makes *no* assumptions about the distribution of the predictor variables (except, for some applications, that the predictor variables are observed without error).  The choice of the response distribution (e.g. Gaussian vs Poisson vs Gamma, zero-inflated or not, ...) is all about the *conditional* distribution of the *response* variable.

A predictor variable with lots of zeros will generally lower your statistical power/resolution (because there's not very much information to use if most of your observations have the same value of the predictor variable), but there's not much you can do about that (besides try to collect different data).